# How to convert Cassandra/ScyllaDB text to bigint and vice-versa?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

In PostgreSQL I can do this:

```
SELECT (col::BIGINT+1)::TEXT + '%' FROM bar WHERE id = 1
UPDATE bar SET col = (col::BIGINT+1)::TEXT WHERE id = 1
```

How to do this in Cassandra/ScyllaDB? I need to convert TEXT to BIGINT and back to TEXT to update a column value, the column itself must be a TEXT because it doesn't store only number.

Comment: If your column does not store only numbers, what do you do with values that cannot be cast to BIGINT?

Comment: Cast has been introduced in Cassandra 3.2, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10310. But casting from TEXT to BIGINT is not supported so you would need to implement your own UDF like Ashraful Islam suggested.

Comment: @adutra, that one record with id=1 stores number, others can be number or not only number, so I can't make the type BIGINT, because other ID may store alphanumeric

Comment: Fair enough, but in this case a better model would be to store this value in two columns, one varchar and other int or bigint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default function to this in cql. But you can create one, see [UDF](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html). Cassandra support UDF but Scylladb doesn't supports UDF yet

Let's create these function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigintAstext (input bigint) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS text LANGUAGE java AS 'return String.valueOf(input);';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION textAsbigint (input text) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE java AS 'return Long.parseLong(input);';
```

Here `bigintAstext` will convert bigint to text and `textAsbigint` will convert text to bigint

How to use ?

Let's create a table and insert data

```
CREATE TABLE udf_test (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    data text
);

INSERT INTO udf_test (id , data ) VALUES ( 10, '10');
```

Now you can query like :

```
SELECT bigintAstext(id), textAsbigint(data) FROM udf_test ;
```

Output :

```
 test.bigintastext(id) | test.textasbigint(data)
-----------------------+-------------------------
                    10 |                      10
```

Note : UDFs (user defined functions) are disabled by default, you can enable it by setting `enable_user_defined_functions: true` on `cassandra.yaml`

Comment: too bad this didn't work on scylla. `SyntaxException: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'CREATE'`

Comment: It doesn’t look like Scylladb supports UDF yet: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/2204